# Separate segment and encrypt steps for Adobe HDS

Tags: flash, adobe, http-live-streaming

Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming (HDS)'s [File Packager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/HTTPStreaming/1.0/Using/WSaeac10ab694095a12a9a3a7d12823cda643-7ffc.html) supports segmenting and encrypting video files with one command.

However, we have a workflow need whereby we perform additional processing steps on segmented files before we encrypt those files.

With HLS (HTTP Live Streaming), this is easy to do as the encryption step uses AES-128 encryption, which is open and widely implemented.

Is this possible with HDS? It does not seem possible based on brief reading of the page, but there may be additional knowledge out there that proves me wrong.

Comment: Would a workflow in which you segment, perform your additional processing, concatenate, and then resegment+package work?

Comment: It might. Is there a known method to concatenate segments?

Answer (score 1):

I would contact Adobe and ask them about the processing you want to perform after segmenting, but before encryption. Adobe Flash Acces has multiple levels of encryption, so it may be possible, if you can do the job with partial encryption.  Here is a document about Adobe Access Server - http://www.adobe.com/support/adobeaccess/pdfs/server/AdobeAccess_4_ProtectingContent.pdf.